# Qt development of color analyzer upper computer ca410

Tags: qt

When linking to a third-party library in QT, the library was found, but the interface in the library cannot be called and the display is undefined. What is the reason for this? It is the SDK of a color analyzer CA410

I have changed the version of QT and updated the latest version of SDK. I would like to know if QT can develop CA410 and how to solve library errors

Comment: I think you might have to add more details to your question, such as: **1/** Qt versions you used? **2/** version of the SDK you're using? **3/** how exactly have you linked this library? **4/** what errors have you got exactly? **5/** could you explain how your problem could reproduced? **6/** What platform are you on?